# angular 6 detect mouse over with file

Tags: angular, file-upload, drag-and-drop, hover

I'm making my own file upload drop zone.

I can easily set a variable to true or false like so :

```
<div (mouseenter)="dropzoneHovered = true" (mouseleave)="dropzoneHovered = false">
```

but this does not trigger when I am hovering with a file about to be dropped :

[image]

How can I detect that type of hover instead of a fileless hover?

(it's the only type that should trigger animations and events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `dragenter` and `dragleave`. Change your template to this and try dragging a file over it:

```
<div (dragenter)="dropzoneHovered = true" (dragleave)="dropzoneHovered = false">
```

But note that this also fires when you drag text over your target. To get around that, use something like [this solution from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-if-dragenterdragover-event-contains-files/). Here's a quick [example of this running in an Angular app on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-and-drop?file=src/app/app.component.html). Try dragging text/files over each of those divs and observe the outcome.

Comment: why is the trigger so iffy? i can reliably get it to trigger when I enter very rapidly but when I enter slowly or very slowly it doesn't trigger.

Comment: I figured it out : I got much more consistent results with `(dragover)="dropzoneHovered = true" (dragleave)="dropzoneHovered = false"`